# Lotus notes data to Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, splist

I have a question and hope you guys can point me in right direction. I am not so much aware of lotus notes architecture. I have a lotus notes db that needs to be moved to a sharepoint list. I know there are tools out there to do this job.

1) My question is, is it possible to write an API to move data from notes to splist? (This is one time only). If yes, can you please point me in right direction.

2) If we have to use a tool, which tools are the best. How do we decide which tool (what are the criterias). Can the tools be configured to transfer records in a specific way (taking splist content types into picture and sharepoint limitition on number of items in a list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 It is certainly possible to write API for this. I don't know which direction to go but obviously studying the NOTES API first and SharePoint API is must. SharePoint API is well established and can be easily accessed using .NET framework.

Regarding Notes, I am not sure if its documented but I feel that it would be playing with unmanged (COM) code.

2 As a tool,I have used CASAHL many times for this purpose and would certainly recommend it.

http://www.casahl.com/

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one last question. What are the parameters in deciding which tool to use.

Comment: Check if tool supports data transformation, you will certainly require it. How does tool handle complex data types of sharepoint such as Rich Text, Pictures, Attachments. Can it migrate notes attachment directly as sharepoint attachment ? What about performance ? How much time does it take to migrate the list data with 1 million records .... Many parameters

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend Domigrator from Donova AB, this is a very effective and good tool for migrating domino Applications to SharePoint. This by far the best and smartest tool to use, it has no problem with customized databases or Rich Text and what so ever. You can find the tool on their website: http://www.donova.com/en/domigrator/

Answer (score 0):

If you are only talking about one database, you might take an easier approach.  How about exporting the data to Excel?  You can then import the list to SharePoint very easily.

If you're moving multiple "lists" from Notes to SharePoint, you'll need to rewrite any logic that allows them to interact.  That is unless you are using an unmodified template in Notes such as a discussion board, etc.  In that case there are some tools to help you move the entire application.  Because they are such different platforms, though, I usually find only the data can be moved.